# Как изменить размер статик поля

Tags: c++, winapi, gui

Есть код.

```
hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST, "PBP", str, WS_OVERLAPPED, 0, 0, 50, 50, NULL, NULL, wc.hInstance, NULL);
hLogo = CreateWindowW(L"Static", NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_BITMAP, 0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Как можно изменить высоту и ширинру статик поля? Сейчас он 0 в высоту и 0 в ширину. Но дальше по коду мне нужно изменить высоту на 50 и ширину на 50. Если я использую команду

```
SetWindowPos(hLogo, NULL, 0, 0, 50, 50, NULL);
```

или

```
MoveWindow(hLogo, 0, 0, 50, 50, true);
```

то он установит не правильный размер, так как будет учитывать размер TitleBar'а.

Какой функцией я могу правильно изменить размер "Static"?

Comment: Размер чего нужно изменить? В вопросе встречаются "поле", строка, окно

Comment: изменить высоту и ширину статик поля.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например вот так:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <memory>

LRESULT WINAPI wnd_proc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    if (msg == WM_DESTROY) {
        ::PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    return ::DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    ::std::memset(&wc, 0, sizeof WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.cbSize = sizeof WNDCLASSEX;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"MyWndClass";
    wc.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    wc.hCursor = ::LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hInstance = ::GetModuleHandle(nullptr);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.hIcon = ::LoadIconW(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hIconSm = ::LoadIconW(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hbrBackground = HBRUSH(::GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH));
    wc.lpfnWndProc = wnd_proc;

    if (!::RegisterClassExW(&wc)) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    LONG styles = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_BORDER | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU | WS_CAPTION;

    HWND window_handle = ::CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_TOPMOST, wc.lpszClassName, L"Some Window", styles, 100, 100, 100, 100, HWND_DESKTOP, nullptr, wc.hInstance, nullptr);

    if (!window_handle) {
        ::UnregisterClass(wc.lpszClassName, wc.hInstance);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    const int desktop_size_w = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    const int desktop_size_h = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    RECT calculate_rect{ 0, 0, 500, 500 };
    ::printf_s("::AdjustWindowRect: %s\n", ::AdjustWindowRect(&calculate_rect, styles, FALSE) == TRUE ? "true" : "false");
    ::printf_s("%d x %d\n", calculate_rect.right - calculate_rect.left, calculate_rect.bottom - calculate_rect.top);

    ::ShowWindow(window_handle, SW_NORMAL);
    ::UpdateWindow(window_handle);

    const int window_w = calculate_rect.right - calculate_rect.left;
    const int window_h = calculate_rect.bottom - calculate_rect.top;

    ::SetWindowPos(window_handle, nullptr, desktop_size_w / 2 - window_w / 2, desktop_size_h / 2 - window_h / 2, window_w, window_h, 0);

    RECT client_rect{ 0 };

    ::GetClientRect(window_handle, &client_rect);

    ::printf_s("client rect: [ %dx%d ]\n", client_rect.right - client_rect.left, client_rect.bottom - client_rect.top);

    MSG msg{ 0 };

    while (::GetMessageW(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {
        ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
        ::DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Результат:

```
::AdjustWindowRect: true
516 x 539
client rect: [ 500x500 ]
```

Comment: windowHandle = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST, "PBP", str, WS_OVERLAPPED, 0 , 0, 100, 100, NULL, NULL, wc.hInstance, NULL);
  


RECT r{ 0, 0, 500, 500 };
::AdjustWindowRect(&r, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_BITMAP, FALSE);
  ::SetWindowPos(windowHandle, NULL, 0, 0, r.right - r.left, r.bottom - r.top, NULL);

получается 486 на 493

Comment: Так, и в чем проблема? Все правильно, вы класс вашего окна приложите к вопросу, что бы было более понятно. У вас же указаны стили как `WS_OVERLAPPED`.

Comment: А вы туда зачем то кладете указанные мной в ответе, там же явно написано для вашего `Static`, `WS_OVERLAPPED` туда поместите, и ваше окно будет рассчитано так, что размер пользовательской части будет именно `500х500`.

Comment: RECT r{ 0, 0, 500, 500 };
  ::AdjustWindowRect(&r, WS_OVERLAPPED, FALSE);
  printf("w:%d h:%d\n", r.right - r.left, r.bottom - r.top); 486 на 493

Comment: Смотрите обновленный ответ, и ищите ошибки у себя.